# Is it wrong to use sub substitution for evaluating integrals?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, substitution

I have an integral

$\int\frac{\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}}{(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3})^2+1} \,\text{d}x$

I am replacing $\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}$ with $t$ so I have

$\int\frac{t}{t^2+1}\,\text{d}t$ is it wrong if I replace now $t^2+1$ with $u$ and then have 
 $\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u}$ so this is $\ln(u)=\ln|t^2+1|=\ln|\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}|$ all the result $\frac{1}{2}\ln|\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}|$ if wrong can someone explain why ?

Comment: It is fine to say $t = \frac {2x-1}{\sqrt 3}$ but then you must say $dt = \frac {2}{\sqrt 3} dx \implies dx = \frac {\sqrt 3}{2} dt$

Comment: oh yes so the result in the end should be the same but  $\frac{\sqrt3}{4}$ right ?

Comment: and it must be squared and +1 i forgot to add

Comment: so there is no problem in using a double substitution

Comment: As long as each substitution is applied correctly, you can do multiple substitutions.

Comment: yes I see thanks for your answer , seems I was doing it wrong and getting different results so I was confused if it doesnt work